# Unable to create a new transaction using @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) with HibernateTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I am currently refactoring some legacy code.

We are moving from .xml spring context files to java class based Spring configuration.

Here is the TransactionConfiguration.java class that I have created for Spring initiation of my TransactionManager.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TransactionConfiguration
{
  private String[] packagesToScan = {...redacted...};

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource(@Value("${db.driverClassName}") String driverClassName, @Value("${db.url}") String jdbcUrl,
          @Value("${db.usr.login}") String username, @Value("${db.usr.password}") String pwd, @Value("${db.maxPoolSize}") int maxPoolSize)
  {
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(pwd);
    dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource, @Value("${db.schema}") String dbSchema, @Value("${db.dialect}") String dbDialect,
          @Value("${db.show.sql}") Boolean dbShowSql, @Value("${db.hbm2ddl.auto}") String hbm2dll)
  {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan);

    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.default_schema", dbSchema);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", dbDialect);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", dbShowSql);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2dll);

    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

    return sessionFactory;
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory)
  {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory.getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }
```

This works fine and my application is able to read/write in database.

However, at some point, I need to create a write transaction from a readOnly transaction.

I've tried to use @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) annotation to ensure the creation of a new write transaction but it does not work.

```
@Service
public class Service1{

  @Autowired
  private Service2 service2;

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public void method1()
  {
    [... read only treatment...]

    service2.method2();

    [... read only treatment...]
  }

}

@Service
public class Service2{

  @Autowired
  private Service3 service3;

  
  public void method2()
  {
    [... read only treatment...]

    method3();

    [... read only treatment...]
  }

  private void method3()
  {
    [... read only treatment...]

    service3.method4();

    [... read only treatment...]
  }

}

@Service
public class Service3{

  @Value("${my.test.prop}")
  private String myTestProp;

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void method4()
  {
    System.out.println(myTestProp);    

    [... write treatment...]
  }

}
```

It did work in the legacy code with .xml configuration and declaration of a TransactionProxyFactoryBean

```
<bean class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>
                <prop key="method1">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
                <prop key="method2">PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I made sure that the two methods are in separate classes so Spring Aop does interact with the second @Transactional annotation

I did activate logback to log transaction creation and I see that no new transaction is created.

I have tried to switch to JPATransactionManager but it did not improve my issue (in fact it did poorly since readOnly instruction was ignored...)

I also tried a NESTED propagation but again it did not start a new Nested transaction

EDIT:

Spring version 5.3.6

Hibernate version 5.4.33

Comment: If there is no transaction created there is no proxy or the code you show here isn't the actual code you use (and the method is not `public` or `final` or ... Make sure the class is spring managed. Tip instead of injecting the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` into your `transactionManager` method, inject a `SessionFactory`. Spring will inject the proper thing (saves yuo from calling `getObject`).

Comment: @M.Deinum: my class is indeed spring managed. It is indeed not the real code but the idea is the same. I know that in the real code the first "readOnly" transaction is created since I do have an exception because of the readOnly. Both methods and classes are public.

Comment: Is the class or rather the instance you have really managed by spring? However the little information you provided here doesn't show anything that shouldn't work. So we would need more information to help you solve this.

Comment: @M.Deinum I do think that both service classes are managed by Spring since they are both instantiated using @Service/@Autowired annotations (I've edited my example to show this). However, I am probably confused about what Spring managed really means. What type of information can I add to help?

Comment: `@Autowired` doesn't instantiate anything, make sure you aren't using `new` in your code for objects that should be spring managed. Your sample is too simplistic to represent your real use case, provide a representative sample.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have modify my example again to try and give a more representative example. The issue is that since my business code is sensitive, I cannot share it. Concerning the Spring management I made sure that no "new" was involved. Moreover, i've added an `@Value` in my "Service3" to test if spring does instantiate this service. I do see "myTestProp" value in console log when running my code.

Comment: The fact that Spring instantiates something doesn't mean that that is the instance in use (trust me I have seen weird setups in all my years with Spring). I'm sorry but adding additional classes in the mix won't change it. There must be something specific in your code that does this, as you have here a dumbed down version of your code (whilst you might think you haven't) from this point it is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In posted class method1() is calling method2() and both annotated with transactional. As I have used in my application according to that You can add  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,readOnly = true) on your method1(), it will work for both method1() and method2(). Because method2() is called inside method1().

```
   @Service
public class Foo{

  @Autowired
  private Bar bar;

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,readOnly = true)
  public void method1()
  {
    bar.method2();
  }

}

@Service
public class Bar{

 
     public void method2()
      {
        ...
      }

   }
```

Comment: My bad, I think my example was not explicit enough. I do need method1 to be in a readOnly transaction while method2 shall be in a new readOnly=false transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue.

As **M. Deinum** stated in his comments, it was a pure Spring Configuration issue.

The fact is that during the refactoring of the legacy code, the following block of code made its way into a java Spring Configuration file.

```
@Bean
  MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean(DefaultSecurityManager securityManager)
  {
    MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();

    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setStaticMethod("org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager");
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(securityManager);

    return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
  }
```

My DefaultSecurityManager is dependent on my Service where my `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` is.

This block of code disrupts the normal flow/init of Spring and the `@Transactional` annotation get ignored.

This explains why during Spring init my method is not identified as transactional and no new transaction is started when the method is called.

Replacing the wrong block of code by a simple call to the correct Set method does resolve the issue

```
SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(result);
```

Thank you all for your time and help.